# Gravity as part of the metric but not of a 4-vector potential

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, potential, classical-field-theory

In class, I've been told that the scalar potential $V(x)$ (except the one associated to gravity) has to be introduced in the Lagrangian as the time-component of a 4-vector potential $A_\mu$, so what you have in the interaction Lagrangian is

$$
L_{int} = -\int d\lambda\ A_\mu v^\mu, \quad v^\mu = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \lambda}, \quad (A_\mu) = (V(x), \vec{A}(x))
$$

With $x^\mu(\lambda)$ the trajectory of the particle that interacts with the field and $\lambda$ the parameter of the curve.

But the Professor told us this was only good for non-gravitational potentials because if you try to introduce the gravitational potential in this way, it would be repulsive instead of attractive.

Nonetheless, I don't see why the potential would be like that since we can redefine $A_0 = -V(x)$ if $V(x)$ is repulsive, getting $A_0$ as attractive then.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Repulsive or attractive refers to the interaction of two point particles with like charges mediated through the long range field (EM or gravitational). If you change the definition of the EM potential you would also change the sign of interaction with the second charge and the force between two like charges would still be repulsive.

Comment: @A.V.S. Force is $F = -dV/dx$, let's say $dV/dx < 0$ so $F$ is repulsive. If we change $V \rightarrow -V$, then $F = -d(-V)/dx = dV/dx < 0$ and therefore $F$ is attractive now

Comment: But $V$ does not just magically appear. The potential in which the first particle moves is created by the second particle. Flipping the sign in the definition of $V$ would also change the sign in the potential produced by that second particle resulting in the same force.

Comment: @A.V.S. When you say "Flipping the sign in the definition of $V$ would also change the sign in the potential produced by that second particle", don't you mean that flipping sign in $V$ implies changing the sign of the charge? It's like you are saying that changing $V$ implies changing $V$. I'm sorry but I think I'm  not getting you. Could you elaborate it more? Anyway that doesn't solve my question since I don't see why gravity can't be a 4-vector potencial